# Which stoplist am I using?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

How do I determine which stoplist was associated with my full text index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT FI.fulltext_catalog_id,
       FI.stoplist_id,
       FS.stopword
FROM   sys.fulltext_indexes FI
       LEFT JOIN sys.fulltext_stopwords FS
         ON fi.stoplist_id = fs.stoplist_id
```

**Note:** Selected information is available in `sys.fulltext_stopwords` table but to get the other info related `fulltext_catalog` joined `fulltext_indexes` table